# Different navhost fragment for every activity

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-navigation

Im building an app with conditional navigation based on the values of the login token received.
So I have three different landing pages for my app based on three diffrent values i revceive after decoding the token.
So Iam using three different activties each with its own set of Navigation Graphs and NavHostFragment.
Problem is as soon as I declare another navhost fragment in second activity, app is crashing whenever that activity is opened, with error: "Binary XML file line #36: Duplicate id 0x7f09018a, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"

Following is how I declare navhost fragment in first activity:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNav"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />
```

And this is how I declare navhost fragment in second activity:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_supervisor"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNav"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph_supervisor" />
```

Please help.